# init, cron, and am interaction

Tags: android, scripting, cron

first time poster here. I have a problem with android. I have cron daemon set up to run a script every once and a while. This script has alarms built in to it that trigger when the script fails or succeeds. The alarms use "am" commands to activate actions on some APKs (one wakes the device, the other plays music and or vibrates).

The script works fine. However, when it is called from the crond it behaves abnormally. dmesg shows init killed the process as per this bit of code:

svc = service_find_by_pid(pid);
    if (!svc) {
        ERROR("untracked pid %d exited\n", pid);

Obviously my script is not in the init.rc file, nor is crond for that matter, as a service (my phone is locked/reloads init.rc from ramdisk every boot). Is there a manner of fixing this problem without editing the init.rc?

Answer (score 1):

this walkthrough seems like it had you in mind:

http://howto.ccroms.net/howto/cron

> As I have always wanted an actual cron installation on my phone, I
>   worked on patching vixie-cron for just that. Below are the tales of my
>   adventures:

Comment: The domain ccroms.net may be for sale.